# Is there way to retrieve appRoleName using Graph API call?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to get AppRoles for user. Response contains AppRoleId and does not contain AppRoleName. Is there a way to achieve this?

Calling below Graph API request to get Roles defined for specific user through Postman. Apply Permission as per Microsoft document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
#HTTP request 
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/appRoleAssignments
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhv7H.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the screenshot you provided, you have got the `resourceId`, then you only need to use the resourceId to get `appRoles`, and then find the corresponding `appRoleName` according to your `appRoleId`.

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{your resourceId}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carl. But this will get me all roles of application assigned at manifest level but not those roles which are assigned to signed in user. There can be 2 roles in manifest but signed in user might have 1 role. I need roles for signed in user.

Comment: @RohitPachnanda   As I said in the answer, you have got the `resourceId`, you can get the collection of `appRoles` based on the resourceId, then you can loop through the appRoles collection in the code to get a single appRoles, and then you can make an `if` judgment to make appRoleId equal to you The appRoleId obtained previously. Finally, use the appRoleId you previously obtained as the `key`, appRoleName as the `value`, and use the key to obtain the value.

Comment: @RohitPachnanda   If you have any questions, I will answer you as soon as possible.

Comment: @RohitPachnanda  I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Can you accept it as an answer?( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) :)

Comment: @RohitPachnanda Does Carl's answer useful to you ? If also have any questions, you can tell us. If his solution helps you, you can mark his answer as accepted, you can help more forum users.